# What is the correct way to put a transparent background color?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, imageview

It is supposed that this code #272727a6 is a dark almost black color with a% 30 of transparency but it seems blue in android, while in CSS code or in web, the color if it is transparent black, what am I doing wrong? or in Android the Hex code works differently?

```
        Android.Hardware.Camera camara;
        ISurfaceHolder camaraHolder;
        SurfaceView camaraPre;
        RelativeLayout contenedorBtnCaptura;
        ImageButton btnCamara;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Camara);
            contenedorBtnCaptura = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.contenedorBtnCaptura);
            contenedorBtnCaptura.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#272727a6"));
            btnCamara = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnCamara);
            btnCamara.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.btnCapturar);
            btnCamara.SetOnTouchListener(this);
            btnCamara.Click += delegate
            {
                ProcesarCaptura();
            };
            camaraPre = FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.surfaceCamara);
            camaraHolder = camaraPre.Holder;
            camaraHolder.AddCallback(this);
            camaraHolder.SetType(SurfaceType.PushBuffers);
        }
```

Comment: try this color #4D000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black -> #000000

If you want transparency, add 2 chars after #:

Full transparent --> #(00)000000 = **#00000000**

Full opaque --> #(ff)000000 = **#ff000000**

So, 8 characters after the # (2 of transparency + 6 of color)

Between 00 and ff you have 256 different transparency levels :)